# how to solve, Step #3 - "unit-test-on-operator-code": Error response from daemon: manifest for apache/airflow:master not found

Tags: python, maven, build, cloud, platform

Hi I am following this tutorial on gcp. https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cicd-pipeline-for-data-processing

And get an error when running this command.

```
gcloud builds submit --config=build_deploy_test.yaml --substitutions=\
REPO_NAME=$SOURCE_CODE_REPO,\
_DATAFLOW_JAR_BUCKET=$DATAFLOW_JAR_BUCKET_TEST,\
_COMPOSER_INPUT_BUCKET=$INPUT_BUCKET_TEST,\
_COMPOSER_REF_BUCKET=$REF_BUCKET_TEST,\
_COMPOSER_DAG_BUCKET=$COMPOSER_DAG_BUCKET,\
_COMPOSER_ENV_NAME=$COMPOSER_ENV_NAME,\
_COMPOSER_REGION=$COMPOSER_REGION,\
_COMPOSER_DAG_NAME_TEST=$COMPOSER_DAG_NAME_TEST
```

The error I get is:
 **"Step #3 - "unit-test-on-operator-code": Error response from daemon: manifest for apache/airflow:master not found".**

This is what the yaml specifies for step 3.

```
- name: apache/airflow:master
  entrypoint: 'python'
  args: ['test_compare_xcom_maps.py']
  dir: '$REPO_NAME/workflow-dag'
  id: 'unit-test-on-operator-code'
```

Anyone know where the error is and how to solve it?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a tag fo apache/airflow:master. I do see a tag for apache/airflow:master-ci. https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow/tags

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't think I understand what it means that that tag is not available, can you explain? Should I change name in my yaml file for step three to apache/airflow:master-ci

Comment: It works; thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think the docker containers in the docker hub are well maintained for airflow. It looks like from the time the tutorial you were using to now, they changed the names for the tags. Usually tags are used for different architectures.